# Grading in Lagrangian Floer homology

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

What are the conditions on a symplectic manifold (M,w) and on a  Lagrangian submanifold L so that Lagrangian Floer complex CF(L, f(L)) is Z-graded? Here f is a compactly supported Hamiltonian isotopy. Also, what about the conditions for the case when CF(L, f(L)) is defined over Z and also is Z-graded?

Comment: For details, see Seidel's book. Be careful that $\mathit{CF}^\ast(L,L)$ needs to be well-defined, which is not always the case, even though one is not working necessarily over $\mathbb{Z}$.